# When using pathlib, getting error: TypeError: invalid file: PosixPath('example.txt')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I'm using Python 3's [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path(__file__).parent / "example.txt"
contents = open(filename, "r").read()
```

But I get this error on some machines:

```
TypeError: invalid file: PosixPath('example.txt')
```

But on my machine it works.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) integrates seemlessly with `open` only in Python 3.6 and later. From [Python 3.6's release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html):

> The built-in `open()` function has been updated to accept `os.PathLike` objects, as have all relevant functions in the `os` and `os.path` modules, and most other functions and classes in the standard library.

To get it to work in Python 3.5 and Python 3.6, just convert the object to a string:

```
contents = open(str(filename), "r").read()
```

Comment: Or `with open(str(filename)):`

Comment: or if you know it's a Path object: `filename.open()` or a higher-level function like `filename.read_text()`

Comment: Thanks. Switched from 3.6+ to 3.5 and was getting this weird error.