# Python glob gives no result

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.5, glob

I have a directory that contains a lot of `.csv` files, and I am trying to write a script that runs on all the files in the directory while doing the following operation:

> Remove the first and last lines from all the csv files

I am running the following code:

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('path/to/directory/*.csv')
for file_name in list_of_files:
    fi = open(file_name, 'r')
    fo = open(file_name.replace('csv', 'out'), 'w')  #make new output file for each file
    num_of_lines = file_name.read().count('\n')
    file_name.seek(0)
    i = 0
    for line in fi:
        if i != 1 and i != num_of_lines-1:
            fo.write(line)

    fi.close()
    fo.close()
```

And I run the script using `python3 script.py`. Though I don't get any error, I don't get any output file either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code. First of all you count the number of lines on the **filename** instead of the file-object. The second problem is that you initialize `i=0` and compare against it but it never changes.

Personally I would just convert the file to a list of "lines", cut off the first and last and write all of them to the new file:

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('path/to/directory/*.csv')
for file_name in list_of_files:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as fi:
        with open(file_name.replace('csv', 'out'), 'w') as fo:
            for line in list(fi)[1:-1]:  # for all lines except the first and last
                fo.write(line)
```

Using the `with open` allows to omit the `close` calls (because they are done implicitly) even if an exception occurs.

---

In case that still gives no output you could a `print` statement that shows which file is being processed:

```
print(file_name)  # just inside the for-loop before any `open` calls.
```

---

Since you're using python-3.5 you could also use `pathlib`:

```
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path('path/to/directory/')

# make sure it's a valid directory
assert path.is_dir(), "{} is not a valid directory".format(p.absolute())

for file_name in path.glob('*.csv'):
    with file_name.open('r') as fi:
        with pathlib.Path(str(file_name).replace('.csv', '.out')).open('w') as fo:
            for line in list(fi)[1:-1]:  # for all lines except the first and last
                fo.write(line)
```

---

As Jon Clements pointed out there is a better way than `[1:-1]` to exclude the first and last line by using a generator function. That way you will definitely reduce the amount of memory used and it might also improve the overall performance. For example you could use:

```
import pathlib

def ignore_first_and_last(it):
    it = iter(it)
    firstline = next(it)
    lastline = next(it)
    for nxtline in it:
        yield lastline
        lastline = nxtline

path = pathlib.Path('path/to/directory/')

# make sure it's a valid directory
assert path.is_dir(), "{} is not a valid directory".format(p.absolute())

for file_name in path.glob('*.csv'):
    with file_name.open('r') as fi:
        with pathlib.Path(str(file_name).replace('.csv', '.out')).open('w') as fo:
            for line in ignore_first_and_last(fi):  # for all lines except the first and last
                fo.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get any output, not even using `print(file_name)`. I tried both `glob` and `pathlib`, but still no output.

Comment: Could you check what (in the `pathlib` solution) a `print(path.is_dir())` returns?

Comment: Earlier I had tried [this](https://github.com/AnanDvd/MPI-Pigino/blob/master/new_no_first-last.py), and it worked, but only on one file

Comment: `print(path.is_dir())` doesn't return anything either

Comment: Did you put it outside of the loop (just after the `path = pathlib.Path('path/to/directory/')` line)?

Comment: I put it [exactly](https://github.com/AnanDvd/MPI-Pigino/blob/master/new_no_first-last_glob.py) where you mentioned, right inside the `for` loop

Comment: @dvd I updated the `pathlib` solution. That should make sure that your `Path` is actually a valid directory. If it's not a valid directory then the program will throw an `AssertionError` and indicates that you haven't specified the correct path.

Comment: You are right, now it gives an `AssertionError`, but I don't get it. To me it looks like that I am passing the proper directory

Comment: Inside my home folder, I have this directory which contains the csv files, so I write `~/FolderName` in the path

Comment: okay, I changed the message in the `assert` to provide the absolute path. That should give you a hint what could have gone wrong.

Comment: @dvd Probably should be just `'FolderName/'` - the `~` indicates that the path is relative to your `$HOME` directory (not relative to the current directory!). However I found a flaw in your `pathlib` solution, I included the complete solution now because calling [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.replace) on a `Path` isn't what you want (sorry that I missed that previously)!

Comment: The `path` is still confusing me. [Here](https://ibb.co/m0jnHF) is a photo of the directory the script is in. If I put anything in the `Path()`, I get an error showing the entire parent path. If I don't put anything there, I get a `Type error: invalid file: PosixPath(file.csv)`

Comment: If I just put a `/` then I don't get any error, but again, no output file either

Comment: @dvd okay, before we go down the relative path buisness on a trial and error basis. Just use the full path of the target directory, e.g `~/home/subfolder/subsubfolder/..../directoryname_of_the_csv_files`. Depending on your OS you can also find the full path if you inspect the properties of a folder, e.g. for [OSX](https://www.josharcher.uk/code/find-path-to-folder-on-mac/).

Comment: I get the same `Assertion error` saying that `/home/username/subfolder/../~/home/username/subfolder/subsubfolder is not a valid directory`. I have tried running the script from various locations, but no luck

Comment: okay, you could try putting the script in the folder where the `csv` files are and run it using this `path = pathlib.Path('.')`.

Comment: Looks like it points to the right location, but now there is an error referring to the output line `with open(pathlib.Path...)`. Error says `TypeError: invalid file: PosixPath('/home/usrname/subolder/subsubfolder')`

Comment: @dvd haha, my bad. I was running that on python 3.6 where they fixed the `open` with a `pathlib.Path`. I'll update the answer (again) to make it work on 3.5 and 3.4.

Comment: Yeah I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694112/when-using-pathlib-getting-error-typeerror-invalid-file-posixpathexample-t)

Comment: Note that the above-mentioned `TypeError` would contain the "absolute path" to your directory. So basically you could just insert that into the `pathlib.Path` call and run it from any directory.

Comment: Should it be `str(path)` instead of `str(p)`? The path error still remains, and if I replace `path(/home/...) ` with `path('.')`, I get error referring to the `with...open('w') as fo` line. Error says `IsADirectoryError: '.'`

Comment: @MSeifert `list(fi)[1:-1]` works if the size is manageable, otherwise you can nick https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e3b50ffd113b2058e5dafd8e425fc68 which I was thinking of using in an answer... Something like: `fo.writelines(ignore_first_last(fi))`

Comment: @dvd Sorry, typo again it should be `str(file_name)`.

Comment: @JonClements That's a clever approach. I had one without using `itertools` that also worked but thought it might be to complicated (for this question). However you're definitely right that a solution with a generator is a must-have if one wants to process large files (or one cares about memory & performance).